# How to combine codes from two android studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, wampserver

Currently i am trying to combine some android studio codes , but i cannot combine and it always have lots of errors , for example some imports . there are way too many errors so decide to share only a few . please help me out -------->

```
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton;
```

what is **snackbar** and **appcompatbutton**.

```
import retrofit2.Call;
import retrofit2.Callback;
import retrofit2.Retrofit;
import retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonConverterFactory;
```

**retrofit2**

I am trying to combine another code which i did on wamp server storing datas

Comment: are you trying this in an emulator or a real device?

Comment: Test URL in rest client

Comment: `http://127.0.0.1l` is not a valid IP

Comment: @SMR a real device

Comment: yeah, so what ip should i put

Comment: @VVB how do i do that

Comment: Try `http://127.0.0.1`. There isn't supposed to be a letter `l` at the end of an IP address.

Comment: @jkdev i tried still cannot

Comment: @WenhanXiao 127.0.0.1 is localhost. Is there a server running on localhost?

Comment: @jkdev yeah 127.0.0.1 links to my wamp mode

Comment: I see you accepted mikek3332002's answer. Did his solution work? (IP address beginning with `192.168.` or `10.`)

Comment: @jkdev it didnt really work . but i thought of the correct answer . i have to use my own IP adress

Comment: @jkdev do you know how to combine android studio and database

Comment: quick question, if i understand correctly, you are running your code on android right? wamp server is run under windows. right? so to connect from android device to your server you should use ip of your windows machine, not localhost, which is in this case your android device

Comment: @user902383 yeah its working now , but now i have two set of android codes that i want to combine them together

Comment: @WenhanXiao your question is very specific, without seeing your code, and knowing what you want to achieve, all what i can say to you is join them in way they work

Comment: @user902383 can you drop me a email so i can share with you my codes , because there are too many codes i dont know how to show you tanks wenhan999@hotmail.com

Comment: @WenhanXiao put it on github, i can have a look if i have some spare time

Comment: @user902383 lol sorry bro, i need to finish by tomorrow .

Comment: @user902383   https://github.com/wenhannn/androidstudio.git

Comment: Voting to close as Typo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `l` in `BASE_URL` is probably the problem. The is no top level domain called `1l`

Try it with only numbers:

```
public static final String BASE_URL = "http://127.0.0.1/";
```

---

If your andrioid code is on a different machine to your 'wampmode' server, use a different ip.

Use the LAN IP of the server, ie: type `cmd /k ipconfig` in Run.  Try the ones beginning with `192.168.` or `10.`

Comment: i deleted it but its the same , it says fail to connect to  "http://127.0.0.1:80

Comment: what type of URL do they require